# Java Jframe freeze when repainting on canvas

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, canvas, repaint

I edit as you recommend by using Swing timer. But my canvas is not responding i mean in this function im filling objects and then i want repaint but it repaints without making the objects green.

```
private void paintSearch(Vector<NodeGraph2D> vector,Graphics graphics2D) {
    if (!vector.isEmpty()) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (repaint) {
                    if (vector == pruferTreeNodes) {
                        vector.elementAt(i).draw((Graphics2D) graphics2D);
                    } else {
                        graphics2D.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        System.out.println(vector.elementAt(i).getNodeGraph().getName());
                        ((Graphics2D) graphics2D).fill(vector.elementAt(i));
                        graphics2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        ((Graphics2D) graphics2D).drawString(vector.elementAt(i).getNodeGraph().getName(), vector.elementAt(i).getX1() + 15, vector.elementAt(i).getY1() + 25);
                    }
                    i++;
                }

            }

        });
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

So timer i think works but i dont know if Swing timer can work with canvas together.

Comment: Use a swing timer instead - you shouldn't be putting the EDT (your main thread) to sleep :)

Comment: Thanks for an idea ill try that :)

Comment: @sleepToken I used swing timer but my canvas is not responding i mean its not filling the objects on canvas. Maybe stupid question but does swing timer work with canvas and repaint ?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your new code? Preferably in a [reprex] in case your issue is somewhere else

Comment: @sleepToken i did :)

Comment: Actually now i think that filling an object with color its not working because i tried to make a function that makes objects with repaints and its working so error must be in filling objects with color.